# RegEx Match Text Between Delimeters

Tags: regex, python-3.x

Bit more of a complicated one that you would first imagine.
I have a text document written in Markdown, and i need to remove the first H1 section:

```
# H1 Header  - delete
## H2 Header  - delete
### H3 Header - delete  

# H1 Header - start here
```

Ignoring the rest of the python script for the moment, i believe my issues lie with my lack of understanding of lookahead / lookbehind. Struggling to get my head around it....
This is a selection of what i have tried so far (have tried many different ways):

```
content = re.sub("#(?!#).*?#(?!#)",'',content, flags=re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL)
content = re.sub("# .*?#(?!#)",'',content, flags=re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL)
```

Essentially i need to replace the content between `#` and `#` without matching on multiple of the same character `#`'s such as `##` or `###`.
Any help with the RegEx for this is appreciated.

Comment: Like `(?<!#)#(?!#).*?(?<!#)#(?!#)`?

Comment: Thanks Wiktor, that works perfectly, however, it removes the `#` from the H1 header where i want it to start. If you wouldnt mind, could you also explain the regex so i can understand it a bit further please? RegEx seems to be that one thing i have never been able to get my head around....

Comment: So, `(?<!#)#(?!#).*?(?=(?<!#)#(?!#))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
(?s)(?<!#)#(?!#).*?(?=(?<!#)#(?!#))
(?<!#)#(?!#)[\s\S]*?(?=(?<!#)#(?!#))
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5LWX2C/1). You need no `(?s)` if you use `re.S` or `re.DOTALL` option.

**Details**

- `(?<!#)#(?!#)` - a `#` not immediately preceded nor followed with `#` chars
- `.*?` - any 0+ chars as few as possible
- `(?=(?<!#)#(?!#))` - a positive lookahead that requires a `#` char not immediately preceded nor followed with `#` chars immediately to the right of the current location.

In Python, use

```
text = re.sub(r'(?<!#)#(?!#).*?(?=(?<!#)#(?!#))', '', text, 1, re.S)
```

where [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) takes the pattern as the first argument, the replacement (it is an empty string since you remove) as the second argument, the text as the third, the *number of replacements* as the fourth, and the modifiers as the last argument.

Comment: Thanks Wiktor, however, when there are multiple H1's further in the document it removes them all - apologies, i should have been clearer in my question: https://regex101.com/r/5LWX2C/2

Comment: Scratch the above. The edit you made with the Python code has worked perfectly. Much appreciated!

Comment: @Dr.Pepper You need no `re.M` since you have no `^`, nor `$` in the pattern.